# My dog has destroyed almost $1200 in earbuds! What can I do?

Tags: dogs, behavior, chewing

My dog keeps on finding, and obliterating headphones by chewing them up to a non-functional state. I have calculated this to cost me more than $1200 in earbuds.

How can I fix this? In other words, where can I find dog-proof earbuds, or make my dog not want to chew them? As a side note, please consider that I don't want hot sauce in my ears.

Comment: I had a similar problem and started always keeping my earbuds inside a small food container with a sealing lid. It's easier than keeping them up high etc, and still small enough to stick in a backpack.

Answer (score 10):

Hide them! Take them somewhere high, on a bookshelf for example, where the dog cannot reach them.

Comment: That would be an excellent idea, but every once and awhile I forget. If only there was a way for me to remember.

Comment: Keep track of the cost, I'm sure you'll remember eventually then ;-) <br>
Does he take other stuff as well then (besides his toys)?

Comment: What if you had a box for the headphones? I mean the headphones after use must go ONLY in that box. And that box would be high enough for the dog not to reach. Then you would remember to always put the headphones there after you finish using them.

Comment: I agree, eventually the mounting costs will remind you to keep them out of the way. I went through 4 pairs of designer glasses before I realised that this is my fault, not his.

Answer (score 5):

Active training. Get a case of cheap earbuds and expose the dog to them under supervision, actively teaching *No! Not yours, do not touch!"

Works for me with cats.

Note: I don't think you told us the dog's age. Puppies chew, period; it's the human's responsibility to direct that to appropriate chew toys.

Comment: I did that with my dog and it works......when I am there. When I am absent though, he doesn't give a damn. And he knows that he did something wrong because of the look that he gives me when I return home (that 'I know I did something bad but I couldn't resist' kind of look)

Comment: In most cases, the "look he gives me when I get home" is the human projecting or the dog responding to the human's mood, rather than the dog "knowing they did something wrong.".

Answer (score 3):

Puppies like to chew on things, especially rubber things like earbuds, wires, AC power cords, irrigation hosing, water hose tubing, shoes, etc.

Your best defense is honestly just putting them up and out of reach. Anything it can reach is fair play.

There is a bitter apple spray that you can use, but it doesn't work 100% of the time and honestly it gives you the false impression you can leave your things laying around and your puppy won't bother them.